# ios google sign in not getting profile scope

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I implemented a while ago google sign in on my app. everything was working. Im requesting a google profile and email scopes and when calling https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= with the token i received in the app and i got the user profile.

today i run the code and i get the token without the profile only email and email verified. log in via android and via web return with profile. the only problem is with the ios. i can see also that the idtoken in ios is smaller then the one i received via android/web

```
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientId

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
```

Comment: Did u find out the answer? I am having that error right now.

Comment: @MinKhantLu no. sorry.

Answer (score 5):

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate=self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate=self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

This is my button on click and it is perfectly working for me.